# Ubuntu 12.04 install goes to blanks screen with cursor

Tags: 12.04, installation

Memtest works fine, but "Try Ubuntu", "Install Ubuntu", and "Check Disk For Defects" go to a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

I'm using the 64bit installer because that is what, I think, works with AMD processors.

Hardware:
AMD Sempron, Award Bios and a Gigabyte video card

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/138598/cant-install-ubuntu-12-04-black-screen/138635#138635

Answer (score 0):

The choice of installer selected by you is fine since AMD Sempron is a 64 bit processor.

But, the the installation is not going beyond the initial black screen may be because your system is not having the basic requirements for 12.04 satisfied I hope.